# Android contacts - custom field icon not showing in android 6

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

## The goal

I'm working on application that keeps own contacts in contacts database. I want to add my own field with my logo that leads to my application's edit form.

## What I did already

Working with this tutorial: http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/
and a couple of other sources i have assembled something like this:

AndroidMainifest.xml:

```
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.MySyncAdapterService" android:process=":contacts">
       <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon">
          <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
       </intent-filter>
       <meta-data android:name="android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE" android:resource="@xml/contacts" />
       <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/sync_contacts" />
    </service>
```

Contacts.xml:

```
<ContactsAccountType xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <ContactsDataKind
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/icon"
    android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.my.contact"
    android:summaryColumn="data2"
    android:detailColumn="data3"
    android:detailSocialSummary="true" >
  </ContactsDataKind>
</ContactsAccountType>
```

## The problem

As can be seen on first image my custom field is displayed with icon properly in Android 4.3. Unfortunatetly Android 6.0.1 does display my field but without the icon.

[image: 4.3 version]
[image: 6.0.1 version]

Any help will be appreciated, I'm running out of hair on my head ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think i resolved my problem. Android 6.0 seems to ignore ContactsDataKind icon property. In order to provide icon for custom field you need to provide action hadndling it. It will use intent filter's icon if it's provided. If not it will use your application's icon.

```
<activity android:name=".ContactActivity">
  <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.my.contact" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Hey, I added this intent filter with my `mimeType` and the icon is still not showing. Any updates? Thank you!

Comment: Did you implement an actual activity?

Comment: if by activity you mean something similar to your ContactActivity, then yes, I have an actual activity which the intent should go to. But the icon isn't showing on the contact card still. The data in the `summaryColumn` and `DetailColumn` shows.

Comment: i have something diff issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851645/add-app-icon-on-contact-not-working-in-marshmallow

Comment: @SzymonDrosdzol can u provide the source code fro this , i am doing the same thing but didnt even get to call onperformsync method in abstractthreadadapter

Comment: Hi, I can't open my application from custom raw in android contacts list. What should I need to mention in my intent filters? Please help me